# android phonegap - navigator.camera is undefined

Tags: android, cordova

I'm completely new to phonegap. I started with phonegap build - by running 'npm install -g phonegap'.
My system is windows7.
When i run the command 'phonegap run android' i'm getting console messages as follows:

```
 [phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment..
 [phonegap] using the local environment
 [phonegap] compiling Android...
 [phonegap] successfully compiled Android app
 [phonegap] trying to install app onto device
 [phonegap] successfully installed onto device
```

I can see the app running on my device (sony Xperia -E).
But when i put in my javascript code:

```
bindEvents: function() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
},
// deviceready Event Handler
//
// The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
// function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
onDeviceReady: function() {
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
},


    // Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    //HERE
    alert(navigator.camera)
}
```

i keep getting alert which say 'undefined'. I checked the same with navigtaor.geolocation, and it wasnt undefined.

I guess it something to do with camera plugin. Am i right?

Please Help

Thanks Forwards

Comment: Have you added `config.xml` in res -> xml -> configfile in your application?

Comment: I'm already have config.xml inside myApp\platforms\android\res\xml

Comment: Do you have this one in your config file `<feature name="Camera">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
    </feature>`

Comment: yes i have this node but navigator.camera still undefined...

Comment: Have you called onDeviceready? In your javascript code?

Comment: `$(function (){
 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});

function onDeviceReady() {
  // Update DOM on a Received Event
receivedEvent: function(id) {

    console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    //HERE
    alert(navigator.camera)
}
  
}` put this in your javascript.

Comment: yes - i updated the code in the question body - the alert goes after deviceready triggered

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47412/discussion-between-happyzzr1400-and-user3110424)

Answer (score 4):

You have to add these things:

--> app/res/xml/plugins.xml

```
<plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher" />
```

--> app/AndroidManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: app/res ? you mean platforms/android/res/xml?
have no res directory in my app root

Comment: yap. You should add it in plugin.xml page

Answer (score 2):

After looking itno [this](https://github.com/paulorbpacheco/CameraTest-Cordova) project i figured out where was my mistake

I tried to use the 'ondeviceready' eventhandler which comes with index.js.

Dont know why yet, but this handler fires when camera is undefined.
After i specified my own handler on the page

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);


function onDeviceReady() {
    alert(navigator.camera);    
}
```

camera became defined

Answer (score 2):

It is supposed to have the [cordova-plugin-camera](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera) plugin added to your PhoneGap/Cordova project, so just this way you'll get the example working.

See the right command:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera
```

Answer (score 1):

Before running phonegap application, make sure you add the lib:

```
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-camera.git
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-media-capture.git
phonegap local plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-media.git
```

If you omit loading the plugin before building the app it will not work, I also had problems sometimes with installed plugins, so if you did install them, try removing and re-adding them, that worked for me. You can check what plugins are installed by:

```
phonegap local plugin list
```

For more information please visit: [Official Phonegap Documenattion](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html)

Regarding: navigtaor.geolocation it is a standard HTML5 call so if the geolocation plugin is not installed (at least on Android) it will be interpreted as a standard HTML5 geolocation call.

Comment: What do you mean by `If you omit loading the plugin before building the app it will not work` I have installed my plugin (e.g. background-geolocation) with command you gave, and the `phonegap local plugin list` does show the plugin, but I get that the plugin is undefined when I do `navigator.plugins.backgroundGeoLocation`. Do  you have any idea why that could be, I am a bit lost with it :/

Comment: What I mean is that first you add the plugin and only after that you build for your device. I assume you are building locally and not in the cloud. So the right sequence will be, install the plugin, than run `phonegap build android` or `phonegap build ios`, then the plugin should work. Having a look at the documentation of the plugin, it says that you have to use the standard cordova geolocation pluging at least once, before using this plugin. Please read: [link](https://github.com/christocracy/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I guess someone needs to make a release.

```
cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-camera && cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera
```